# No shipping rates found for your order

Tags: commerce

I have created a Flat Rate Service and defined 10 dollars base rate. No calculation rules nothing else. But when I am trying to checkout

Shipping service
No shipping rates found for your order. Please continue the checkout process.

Do I need to define any calculation rules etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to define any calculation rules. The problem is that you are checking out when the rule doesn't apply to you. For example, if you do NOT have the role B and you are checking out, when you are checking if the user has the role B, you will get this message.

Comment: Ah! That's an old question and you are right that the problem was of rules. I actually defined the rule to apply the shipping cost where country code is equals AE.

Comment: Glad you solved it :) It recently happened to me.